# Expected MAC different than incoming one from NodeJS to Go server

Tags: javascript, node.js, go, ecmascript-6, hmac

I'm having trouble trying to implement HMAC between my NodeJS and my Go servers. Right now, the expected MAC generated from my Go server is different than the actual MAC coming from my NodeJS server.

```
// NodeJS generated MAC
const generateMAC = (message, secret) => {
  return crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret).update(message).digest('hex');
};

req.headers['blocklist-auth'] = generateMAC(
  JSON.stringify(req.body),
  secret
);
```

Go HMAC Validation (receives MAC from NodeJS and attempts tp validate)

```
func generateMAC(message []byte, secret []byte) []byte {
    mac := hmac.New(sha256.New, secret)
    _, err := mac.Write(message)
    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }
    s := mac.Sum(nil)
    return s
}

// ValidMAC reports whether messageMAC is a valid HMAC tag for message.
func validMAC(message []byte, messageMAC []byte, secret []byte) bool {
    expectedMAC := generateMAC(message, secret)
    log.Infof("E: %s -- M: %s", string(expectedMAC), string(messageMAC), )
    return hmac.Equal(messageMAC, expectedMAC)
}
```

Upon debugging, I logged what the expected MAC looks like and the actual MAC looks like

Expected:
`n\ufffd\ufffdmi\u0015\ufffd|\ufffdE\ufffd\ufffd>\ufffd\u000e0\u0012C1\ufffd\ufffd\ufffds?!\u001a|\ufffdH<!`

Actual:

```
55d31eb5caf5f5046d054fcf39721ba273cd97da66f663f8337e10ac62045197
```

I noticed the lengths of between the expected and actual MAC are different as well. Where the length coming from NodeJS is twice as long as the expected MAC. Not sure why that is.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They seem to produce the same result, but your encoding passed to the digest call in the Node code is `'hex'`.
If you encode the return the same way on both ends, they should match.

```
const crypto = require('crypto')
const generateMAC = (message, secret) =>
  crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret).update(message).digest('base64')
console.log(generateMAC('foo', 'bar'))
```

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/hmac"
    "crypto/sha256"
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
)

func generateMAC(message []byte, secret []byte) string {
    mac := hmac.New(sha256.New, secret)
    _, err := mac.Write(message)
    if err != nil {
        return "oh no"
    }
    return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(mac.Sum(nil))
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(generateMAC([]byte("foo"), []byte("bar")))
}
```

Both of these produce the same output because they're both encoding as base64: `FHkzIYqqvAuLEKKzpcNGhMjZQ0G88QpHNtxycPd0GFE=`.

`.digest()` returns a Buffer by default if no encoding was specified, which you could then also use in a separate `.toString()` using one of [these encodings](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings).